# Delete duplicates from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following schema :

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| system_one_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| system_two_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type          | smallint(6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to delete duplicates, where "duplicate" is defined as either:

1. matching values for both `system_one_id` and `system_two_id` between two rows, or
2. "cross matched" values, ie `row1.system_one_id = row2.system_two_id` and `row1.system_two_id = row2.system_one_id`

Is there a way to delete both kinds of duplicates in one query?

Comment: I'm using mySQL, but I'd like to be as RDBMS-agnostic as possible.

Comment: another important question: if you have 3 duplicate record which one of them you want to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql supports multi-table deletes, so a straightforward join can be used:

```
delete t1
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t1.id > t2.id
  and ((t1.system_one_id = t2.system_one_id
    and t1.system_two_id = t2.system_two_id)
    or (t1.system_one_id = t2.system_two_id
    and t1.system_two_id = t2.system_one_id))
```

The join condition `t1.id > t2.id` prevents rows joining to themselves *and* selects the *later* added row of a duplicate pair to be the one deleted.

---

FYI, in postgres, similar functionality exists, but with different syntax:

```
delete mytable t1
using mytable t2
where t1.id > t2.id
  and ((t1.system_one_id = t2.system_one_id
    and t1.system_two_id = t2.system_two_id)
    or (t1.system_one_id = t2.system_two_id
    and t1.system_two_id = t2.system_one_id))
```

Comment: @theofabry Yes, you can do something like this in postgres, but unfortunately the syntax is different (it's non-standard SQL functionality, and each invented their own syntax to express it). See edit to my answer for the postgres version

Answer (score 1):

Here is a statement (hopefully) selecting all ids of duplicate records, you only need to wrap it with a delete command (that´s your part). ;-)

```
select A.ID from MYTABLE A
left join MYTABLE B on 
(
    (A.SYSTEM_ONE_ID = B.SYSTEM_ONE_ID and A.SYSTEM_TWO_ID = B.SYSTEM_TWO_ID) 
    or 
    (A.SYSTEM_ONE_ID = B.SYSTEM_TWO_ID AND A.SYSTEM_TWO_ID = B.SYSTEM_ONE_ID)
)
where B.ID is not null and A.ID <> B.ID;
```

Comment: Your statement seems to work, but I can't manage to wrap it into a delete command, I do this : 
```DELETE FROM Link C WHERE C.id IN (your_statement)``` (replacing MYTABLE by Link of course), and I get this : 
```ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'C where C.id IN(select A.id from Link A left join Link B on ((A.system_one_id=B.' at line 1```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `least` and `greatest` to select the minimum id of each group and delete rows with other id's.

```
delete from mytable
where id not in (
    select * from (
        select min(id)
        from mytable 
        group by greatest(system_one_id, system_two_id),
        least(system_one_id, system_two_id)
    ) t1
)
```

Comment: I think the logic is wrong, this query assumes `(system_one_id=1,system_two_id=3)` and `(system_one_id=2,system_two_id=2) ` as `duplicate` which are not. also I'm not sure is it possible to do `delete and select at same time on a table`?

Comment: @Farhęg thanks, I've added `least(system_one_id, system_two_id)` to the group by to make sure the system id's are always the same. it is possible to delete at the same time if you wrap the subquery into a derived table like above

Comment: Great, now it's OK I think.

Answer (score 0):

this query starts from min id and then selects only `not selected records in previous selection with regard to system_ids` (`t.id > t2.id`)

```
delete from your_table t
where id not in (select id from 
                (select distinct t.id
                from your_table t
                where 
                (
                      select count(*)
                      from your_table t2
                      where t.id > t2.id
                            and ((t.system_one_id=t2.system_one_id
                                 and t.system_two_id=t2.system_two_id)
                                 or (t.system_one_id=t2.system_two_id
                                 and t.system_two_id=t2.system_one_id))
                ) =0
              ) tbl
            )
```